# Excepting an error from a library an import is using

Tags: python, import, module

I want to `except` `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, which is being raised by a library that I am importing. I am not importing `requests`. How can I `except` this specific exception?

Comment: I imagine you would have to modify the source

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that- if the library is well-written it should raise its own exception when it handles the one from `requests`.

Comment: @AlexThornton the library in this case is [praw](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/errors.py) and this is the exception I'm getting on my traceback. Can i import requests on my own and try to catch it myself?

Comment: @yayu I would imagine that you probably could.

Comment: Why can't you import the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to catch a `ConnectionError` you can import the error and catch it like you would any other error

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
  code_that_raises_connection_error()
except ConnectionError:
  handle()
```